# have a way of AFNetworking return your callback without blocks?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking

I'm using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/0.10.x) library, and it works using blocks to handle your results, like as follow:

```
[httpClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id response) {
    //success clock
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //error block
}]
```

have a way of use it without code blocks? for example using a delegate? something like as follow:

```
[httpClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request delegate:self]
```

and in self class:

```
-(void)afhttpSuccess:(AFHTTPRequestOperation*)op Response:(id)response {
    //success method
}
-(void)afhttpError:(AFHTTPRequestOperation*)op Response:(NSError*)error {
    //error method
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with blocks?

Comment: @jrturton the blocks of AFNetwork retains instances used inside it, and if I send a release to the class, that class will wait the AFNetwork release. "it isn't a block problem anyway, is a AFNetwork problem", And I prefer the delegate + interface or delegate + selector methods too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why a delegate + selector paradigm would be preferable, but I made [this library, which eases the transition from ASI, which has that pattern](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking-ASIHTTPRequest).

Alternatively, you can always just call the success / failure methods in your success/failure callbacks.

Comment: Nice work, I need exactly this for my current project. Thanks.